# Is HDInsight cluster setup based on ADLS persistent?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

Is HDInsight cluster setup based on ADLS a persistent cluster?

What is the similar storage for ADLS in AWS?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is HDInsight cluster setup based on ADLS a persistent cluster?

Yes,based on the statements from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-store):

[image]

BTW,[ADLS Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-storage-gen2#create-a-cluster-with-data-lake-storage-gen2-through-the-azure-portal) is suggested to gain the improved performances.

> What is the similar storage for ADLS in AWS?

You could scan the overview of [Data Lakes and Analytics on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/big-data/datalakes-and-analytics/).Among them,the features of [AWS Lake Formation](https://aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/) is similar to the ADLS,i think.